# This detects violations of my minimum spacing, but does not produce a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I need to generate 10 random numbers with a minimum spacing of 0.15 between any two of them. What I am trying is this:

```
    r=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
     x=random.uniform(1,6)
     r.insert(i,x)
     print(r)
    for j in range(0,9):
      for k in range(0,j):
       h=m[j]-m[k]
       if h<0.15:
          print(h)
       else:
          continue
```

The above code generates 10 random numbers, then I print the difference between pairs when that difference is less than 0.15. This detects violations of my minimum spacing, but does not produce a new list.

Comment: OP, if you can add more information about what you are stuck on, that would be good - it might be a touch broad at present. Nevertheless, I think this should be reopened (the problem is reasonably clear and there is a prior attempt).

Comment: @halfer: Did you read the description in the close message explaining why the question was closed?  If my answer is really that big of a problem, I'll simply remove it.

Comment: @Robert, I agree the question statement could be more specific. I dunno - I've found the general quality here to be so dreadful of late that I tend to defend mostly good questions `:)`. I'm sure the OP will fix it up...

Comment: So what is the actual problem that needs to be solved here anyway?  If it's in the title of your question, the answer is: *write python code that generates 10 random numbers in a range of 0 to 10/1.015, and then multiply each generated number by 1.015.*  That will guarantee a spacing of .015; you won't even have to check it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That won't necessarily work. If `v1 = 0.1` and v2 = `0.11`, then `v2 * 1.015 - v1 * 1.015` is `0.01015`, which is less than `0.015`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a very basic thing, you don't try to recreate the list when it violates your constraints.

I also prefer to break things apart more than this, Python makes it so easy. I've moved your constraint checking into its own function.

```
def meets_constraints(m):
    for j in range(0,9):
        for k in range(0,j):
            h=abs(m[j]-m[k])
            if h<0.15:
                print(h)
                return False
    return True

while True:
    r=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        x=random.uniform(1,6)
        r.insert(i,x)
        print(r)
    if meets_constraints(r):
        break
```

This keeps generating a new list until you obtain one where all of the elements are at least 0.15 apart. Note that this is incredibly inefficient, since checking all the elements is an n^2 algorithm and you will keep performing the test some random number of times until you happen across a sequence that passes. A better algorithm would guarantee the constraint as you're building the list in the first place.

P.S. I've also added an `abs` in the difference calculation, since I think that was a bug in your original code.

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
min_interval=0.15
last=0
for n in range(0,10):
    num=last+random()+0.15
    print num
    last=num
```

Comment: I don't think this will give you a random distribution.  I also don't think it will be within the range of 0 to 10.